# What's the difference between "we don't have time for/ to do that"

Tags: word-usage

What's the difference between:

> 1 we don't have time for that

> 2 we don't have time to do that

Comment: None - they are just slightly different ways of saying the same thing.

Comment: To explain the difference would be splitting hairs.

Answer (score -1):

1. This can be good not only when you about to do something. It can be good in case when you don't want to be involved in some situation as a passive person.
2. This can be good when before was said something about the plan to do something.